# Why is the return value of Request.Form.ToString() different from the result of NameValueCollection.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

It seems like the ToString () in HttpContext.Request.Form is decorated so the result is different 
from the one returned from ToString() whencalled directly on a NameValueCollection:

```
NameValueCollection nameValue = Request.Form;
string requestFormString = nameValue.ToString();

NameValueCollection mycollection = new NameValueCollection{{"say","hallo"},{"from", "me"}};
string nameValueString = mycollection.ToString();

return "RequestForm: " + requestFormString + "<br /><br />NameValue: " + nameValueString;
```

The result is as the following:

RequestForm: say=hallo&from=me

NameValue: System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection

How can I get "string NameValueString = mycollection.ToString();" to return "say=hallo&from=me"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason you don't see the nicely formatted output is because `Request.Form` is actually of type `System.Web.HttpValueCollection`. This class overrides `ToString()` so that it returns the text you want. The standard `NameValueCollection` does *not* override `ToString()`, and so you get the output of the `object` version.

Without access to the specialized version of the class, you'll need to iterate the collection yourself and build up the string:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < mycollection.Count; i++)
{
   string curItemStr = string.Format("{0}={1}", mycollection.Keys[i],
                                                 mycollection[mycollection.Keys[i]]);
   if (i != 0)
       sb.Append("&");
   sb.Append(curItemStr);
}

string prettyOutput = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over `mycollection` and build a string up yourself, formatted the way that you want it. Here's one way to do it:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (string key in mycollection.Keys)
{
   sb.Append(string.Format("{0}{1}={2}",
      sb.Length == 0 ? string.Empty : "&",
      key,
      mycollection[key]));
}

string nameValueString = sb.ToString();
```

The reason that simply calling `ToString()` on your `NameValueCollection` does not work is that the [`Object.ToString()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring.aspx) is what's actually being called, which (unless overridden) returns the object's fully qualified type name. In this case, the fully qualified type name is "System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection".

Answer (score 1):

Another method that works well:

```
var poststring = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```